# Distinct with where condition

Tags: sql

I have table as below:

[image]

I want to perform distinct on city but if city is duplicate then return row which having maximum ref_id. Result should contains all the columns.

Comment: Show us expected result from this sample data and tag your database also

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: `Result should contains all the columns`, if city have multiple equally higher `ref_id` , then which one row  do you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test data:

```
DECLARE @t_temp TABLE (ID     smallint,
                       name   varchar(10),
                       city   varchar(10),
                       ref_id smallint);

INSERT INTO @t_temp
VALUES
(1, 'xyz', 'a', 101),
(2, 'pqr', 'a', 102),
(3, 'ijk', 'a', 103),
(4, 'abc', 'b', 104),
(5, 'ahg', 'c', 10);
```

Actual query:

```
SELECT ID
     , name
     , city
     , ref_id
FROM   (SELECT *
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY ref_id DESC) Ranking
        FROM @t_temp) base
WHERE  Ranking = 1;
```

Result:

```
ID     name       city       ref_id
------ ---------- ---------- ------
3      ijk        a          103
4      abc        b          104
5      ahg        c          10
```

Basicly, what I'm doing is assigning a 'ranking' to all your records grouped by `city` and ordered by `ref_id`, and then retaining only the "number one" record. This is an alternative to what Rahul proposed, which is also a valid solution to your problem. The only difference between the two is that in Rahul's example he'll return multiple records if multiple exist with the same `city` and `ref_id` (considering it being the highest one), where the solution above will only return a single record. To reach the same behavior as Rahul, you can change the `ROW_NUMBER()` to `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Select tb1.* from Table1 as tb1 
inner join (
    Select city, Max(ref_id) as 'ref_id' from Table1 group by city
) as tb2 
on tb1.city = tb2.city and tb1.ref_id = tb2.ref_id
```